# ExpressJs with sequelize

Tags: express, sequelize.js

I have successfully integrated **Sequelize** ORM with Express Js but i am having troble to migrate db in sequelize. Any help?

```
var express = require('express');
var Sequelize = require('sequelize');
var bodyParser =  require('body-parser');
var app = express();

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: false}));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

var router = express.Router();
var sequelize = new Sequelize('tousif', 'root', 'root', {
  host: 'localhost',
  dialect: 'mysql'
});
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In order to use the CLI you need to install the respective package:

```
npm install --save sequelize-cli
```

Further and more detailed information about the available commands can be obtained via the help command:

```
$ sequelize help:init
$ sequelize help:db:migrate
$ sequelize help:db:migrate:undo
```

For further info use this link [Sequelize](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/en/latest/docs/migrations/)

Answer (score 0):

Have you loaded your model and synced the database?  Your code doesn't really show me the rest of your configuration just the connection string.

I suggest after installing sequelize-cli that your use

`$ sequelize help:model:create`

It will tell you how to create a model.

You'll have to import the model files, associate methods, sync those models with the database.

```
  // Expose the connection function
  db.connect = function(database, username, password, options) {
  if (typeof db.logger === 'function')
    console.log("Connecting to: " + database + " as: " + username);

  // Instantiate a new sequelize instance
  var sequelize = new db.Sequelize(database, username, password, options);

  db.discover.forEach(function(location) {
    var model = sequelize["import"](location);
    if (model)
      db.models[model.name] = model;
  });

  // Execute the associate methods for each Model
  Object.keys(db.models).forEach(function(modelName) {
    if (db.models[modelName].options.hasOwnProperty('associate')) {
      db.models[modelName].options.associate(db.models);
      winston.info("Associating Model: " + modelName);
    }
  });

  if (config.db.sync) {
    // Synchronizing any model changes with database.
    sequelize.sync(
      //{ force: true } // use to drop before create
      ).then(function() {
        console.log("Database synchronized");
      }).catch(function(err) {
        console.log(err);
      });
  }
}
```